# Parse-Dashboard - server not reachable unable to connect to server

Tags: parse-server, parse-dashboard

I am trying to install Parse-Server and Parse-Dashboard in Google Cloud (Debian/Jesse). I have already installed on both Windows (locally) and on Heroku and everything worked fine.

My configuration is the following:

- Linux Debian 3.16.43-2
- Node JS 7.10
- Mlab
- Firewall Ports are open

Installed both Parse-Server and Dashboard via **npm**.
I think Parse-Server is running fine since I was able to check that MLab database was written with Parse-Server tables (_SCHEMA, etc).

My Parse Dashboard config file is the following:

```
     {
      "apps": [
        {
          "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
          "appId": "1",
          "masterKey": "654321",
          "appName": "AppName",
          "production": "true"
        }
      ],
      "users": [
        {
          "user":"username",
          "pass":"password"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I run parse-server with this command and it shows the following status:

```
parse-server --appId 1 --masterKey 654321 --databaseURI mongodb://dbAdmin:db123456@Omitted.mlab.com:Omitted/Omitted --serverURL http://127.0.0.0.1/ --port 1337 --appName AppName

appId: 1
masterKey: ***REDACTED***
port: 1337
host: 0.0.0.0
databaseURI: mongodb://dbAdmin:db123456@Omitted.mlab.com:Omitted/Omitted
serverURL: http://127.0.0.0.1/
mountPath: /parse
appName: AppName
maxUploadSize: 20mb
userSensitiveFields: ["email"]
```

I run parse-dashboard with this command and it shows the following status:

```
parse-dashboard --config /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-dashboard/Parse-Dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.mine.json  --allowInsecureHTTP

The dashboard is now available at http://0.0.0.0:4040/
```

I am able to log into Dashboard but it keeps saying:
**server not reachable unable to connect to server**.

I have tried the following list of fixes:

- Changed serverURL to localhost or to 127.0.0.1
- Added /parse at the end of the address
- Changed serverURL port to 1333
- Checked APP ID, APP Masterkey and APP Name
- Opened firewall ports
- Stopped using configuration file

Nothing solves this problem. If anyone has any suggestion, I would very be pleased to try.

Thanks in Advance.
Regards,
James P

Comment: Maybe it's not clear, but this error has happened using a new server with MLab [link](https://mlab.com/). Installing locally or using Heroku, everything has worked fine.

Comment: I have changed MongoDB from Mlab to localhost. I have just verified with a **curl** command that parse-server is running fine. However, parse-dashboard cannot connect to parse-server.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Probably this is not the correct solution, but at least it worked.

The serverURL: http://127.0.0.0.1/ or serverURL: http://localhost/ **did not work for me**. I have changed both parse-server and parse-dashboard to **an external IP for (35.x.x.x, in my case)**.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

**Configuration:**

Installed mongodb, parse-server & parse-dashboard, all 3 on separate docker instances.
Used a 4th docker instance with apache2 to make it work as a reverse proxy.

**Mistake:**

Pointed subdomain parse-dashboard.ABC.com to the parse-dashboard, but did not point parse-server to any subdomain. ***The most important part here is that parse-dashboard uses JavaScript to access app on parse-server, so this resulted in a CORS error.***

**Solution:**

I pointed parse.ABC.com to parse-server.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

Have you started mongodb?

```
sudo service
```

Did you start parse-server before Parse-Dashboard?
In your project folder

```
npm start
```

On another terminal in your project folder start Parse-Dashboard

```
Parse-dashboard --config parse-dashboard-config.json
```

Comment: ztvmark, since I use Mlab, starting mongod is not needed, right?
I start parse server with the command line written above.